# CPQ+ License and eSignature

Tags: cpq, docusign, quote-template

If the org currently has **CPQ+ license** and is planning to use CPQ for document generation and DocuSign for esignature, will we need to convert CPQ templates to DocuSign templates before we can add the signature tag into the templates?

Also, can CPQ+ handle esignature without a third party provider like Docusign or Conga?

I am getting confused based on the explanation from DocuSign page here: https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&rsc_301=&bundleId=izj1586134369853&topicId=yvx1603256593714.html&_LANG=enus

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to convert your CPQ document templates to DocuSign templates to use e-signature. I believe you don't even get that option unless you also purchase document generation package from DocuSign in addition to e-signature.